# Wheels wont rotate in animation but do in edit mode?

Tags: drivers

Situation, i made a wheel, and a empty-cube.
The weel's parent is the empty-cube.
Next for the wheel i created a simple driver.
Based upon the empty cube y-axis movement : 
[image]

When i am in edit mode and drag the empty horizontally the wheel rotates.
But when i animate the cube y locations they dont seem to rotate
also when render the wheel wont rotate.

Comment: I really wonder, how could you drag the empty in mesh edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Well it worked I think the cause was a huge file and blender was active for 2 days. After restart it worked